# Add more/remove functionality is throwing out of validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, html-table

I am trying to submit a form in that I have **Addmore** functionality in it.

**Example:** I have entered name and then I have used addmore button so now remove appeared in second **tr**.
When I click the remove that **tr** is removed now, but when click the form submit button it is skipping the phone number validation,
so to remove the functionality is throwing out validation.

My html somewhat looks like this:

```
<form>
 Name<input type="text"  name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Name Your Name "/>

<table class="skillsTable" id="jobSkills">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="gdskilltr">
   <td><button type="button" class="addSkills"> Add Skill</button></td>
   <td><button type="button" class="removeSkill"> Remove Skill</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

 phone<input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone"  placeholder="enter Your phone "/>

 <button type="submit" id="JobSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

And here my Javascript validation starts:

```
var skillcount = 1;
$(".addSkills").click(function () {
$('#jobSkills tr:last').after('<tr class="gdskilltr "><td></td></tr>');
skillcount++;
});
$("#jobSkills").on('click', '.removeSkill', function () {
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$("#JobSubmit").click(function () {
if ($("#name").val() == '') {
$("#warning_message").html('Please Enter name');
$("#name").focus();
return false;
}

if ($("#phone").val() == '') {
$("#warning_message").html('Please Enter name');
$("#phone").focus();
return false;
}
}
```